# Dictionary value undefined (error)

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, ionic-framework

I want to use a selection string input to search in a dictionary for the correct value, which I then later have to use for a public API.

My selection input comes from this function which is initiated through the selection, and where `InpBox` is the selection.

```
 public dictionary =  {Soccer: "b134", Football: "c568"} ; 

    public optionsFn(): void {       
          this.correct = this.InpBox.toString();
          let test  = this.dictionary[this.correct]; // does not work 
          console.log(this.correct, test)
}
```

The console always returns: `Football , undefined` but it should be `Football , c568`.

Comment: maybe you want to write { "Football": "c568" } instead? Note the quote marks around Football

Comment: I copied like this from the console. The dict comes from another operation.

Comment: Try defining `optionsFn` as an arrow function: `public optionsFn = (): void => { ... }`.

Comment: Silly question -- does `this.correct` have a space in it? The way you are printing the values, `Football , undefined` implies you have a space after "Football". This would definitely not return the correct value from `this.dictionary`. Maybe try `this.InpBox.toString().trim()`?

Comment: It was indeed the space problem @Pearman mentioned... such a stupid mistake. Thank you!!